# Grey overlay when uploading to Vimeo

Tags: embed, vimeo

When we upload a video to vimeo, a grey overlay appears on the video, the background is white before upload and white in IE. Every other browser it has this grey overlay.

An example can be found here by pressing "Watch Video" underneath the photo of the ring.

https://www.clogau.co.uk/jewellery/item/kensington-ring-3skr

I've tried multiple formats when uploading but still not getting anywhere. It could be that there is a default codec all users have on their browsers to keep the background white somehow?

Any help with this would be wonderful

Thank You